# extract coefficient G values in R

Tags: r

```
results <- 

Call:
lm(formula = log(Y) ~ G)

Coefficients:


(Intercept)            G  
     1.6122       0.5647  


$`3388.415_6`

Call:
lm(formula = log(Y) ~ G)

Coefficients:


(Intercept)            G  
      1.994       -2.178
```

How to get G values from it in R?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I edited your question correctly, because the code does not make sense to me but perhaps this will be somewhat like the desired answer:

```
G <- 1:10
Gmod <- lm( rnorm(10) ~ G) ; Gmod
coef(Gmod)["G"]
```

If you have a lot of model-objects in a list strucuture, then perhaps this will work:

```
> lapply( list(Gmod, Gmod), function(mdo) coef(mdo)["G"] )
[[1]]
         G 
0.04917535 

[[2]]
         G 
0.04917535
```

(It does worry me that you have floating point numbers as list indices. It suggests something might have gone wrong in earlier steps.)

Comment: There are lot of G values in the results in the similar way and i need to take them out

Comment: can u get the G values from results data on the top(name i used)..i am getting null

Comment: No. You cannot get anything from that. It's just console output, and not even a complete console output at that.